# What is the difference between saying “HTMLElement.prototype.someFunc =” and “HTMLElement.someFunc =”?

Tags: javascript, methods, member, prototyping

I have, in many ocassions been able to register methods for all HTMLElements in both ways.
So I am curious, is there any difference?
Should I prefer one method over the other one?
What would be the *right* way to do it?

Comment: The right thing would be to not do this at all. The DOM interface does not have to follow the same rules as native JavaScript objects. And in some IE versions you cannot even access the prototype or constructor functions afaik.

Comment: [Kangax wrote about this topic recently.](http://perfectionkills.com/extending-built-in-native-objects-evil-or-not/) Extending DOM ("host") prototypes is generally considered to be a terrible idea.

Comment: Another good article in this regard: [What’s wrong with extending the DOM](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom) (thanks @Pointy for the link).

Comment: If you want to learn in general about prototype inheritance, have a look at the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide).

Comment: @felix-kling Unfortunately I did not ask about that.

Comment: @Mario: Did not ask about what exactly?

Comment: @felix-kling whether it is good or not to do it.

Comment: Well you asked what is the *right* way. And the right way is not to extend the DOM because it is unreliable. If you ask for directions, people will tell you when you are completely going the wrong way...

Comment: I'll add my voice to @Felix's in strongly recommending against doing this, for the reasons he gave. Use a wrapper, it's not that much less convenient.

Comment: @felix-kling I ask what is the right way to extend a class. Not if it is good or not to do it. I hope you can understand this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using prototype is making the function available to all objects in the prototype chain. Its basically extending the class. While other one is just adding a property to the current element. But as Felix suggest the right thing would be not to do this at all.

Answer (score 0):

Because JavaScript is a prototype based language and not a Class based language they keyword `.prototype.variable` or `.__proto__.variable` (for Math) is used to directly access the prototype (Like the Class Definition in classed based languages) and modify it effecting ALL of its instances even if the instances has been created before the prototype is modified. Whereas .variable without accessing the prototype only affects the specified instance.

In short "HTMLElement.prototype.someFunc =" will allow ALL HTMLElements (and prototypes which inherit from HTMLElement" to access someFunc. And HTMLElement.someFunc should only be used to allow a specific instance of HTMLELement access to someFunc.